# Issue in using a custom bitmap field

Tags: blackberry

I want to display an image at the bottom of the screen and make it clickable ,i have created a custom bitmap field ImageButtonField and trying to use it ,but i am getting ImageButtonField cannot be resolved.

```
public class ImageButtonField extends BitmapField
{
    public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image) {
        super(image);
    }

    public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image,Field location) {
        //super(image,location);
    }
    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
        if(Characters.ENTER == character || Characters.SPACE == character) {
            fieldChangeNotify(0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
    }
}


  public NativeScreen() {


           super();
               LabelField title = new LabelField("Calendar DatePicker",
                               LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

              hrzManager = new HorizontalFieldManager() {
                    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
                            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x0007F5ED);
                               graphics.clear();
                              super.paint(graphics);
                 }
              };
             hrzManager.add(title);   
             this.add(hrzManager);
               //The background image.
    backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cryptodemo_jde.png");

   // MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

    VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | 
        Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH ) ;

    BasicEditField bef = new BasicEditField("To: ","",50,BasicEditField.FILTER_EMAIL);

    //The LabelField will show up through the transparent image.
    LabelField labelField = new LabelField("This is a label");

    HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
    //A bitmap field with a transparent image.
    //The background image will show up through the transparent BitMapField image.
    ImageButtonField bitmapField = new ImageButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pimdemo_jde.png"),  Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
        horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField);
    BitmapField bitmapField1 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("attachmentdemo_jde.png"), Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
    horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField1);

    //Add the fields to the manager.
   // verticalFieldManager.add(bef);
   // verticalFieldManager.add(labelField);
    verticalFieldManager.add(horizontalFieldManager);

    //Add the manager to the screen.
    this.add(verticalFieldManager);
```

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace

Comment: @CarlosGavidia class ImageButtonField
    ImageButtonField bitmapField = new ImageButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pimdemo_jde.png"),  Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
                                   ^
1 error

Comment: @CarlosGavidia  i want to make the image clickable and place at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no constructor in your class that lets you do this:

```
ImageButtonField ImageButtonField bitmapField = new ImageButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pimdemo_jde.png"), Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
```

The constructor that you're trying to use requires a Bitmap instance and a **long primitive** (for Field.FIELD_BOTTOM). You should add a constructor with the following signature for your code to work:

```
public ImageButtonField (Bitmap bitmap, long style){
    super(bitmap, style);
}
```

Comment: i need help for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739439/how-to-create-a-list-field-similar-to-native-calendar